# Which zsh shell theme is this?

Tags: arch-linux, theme, icons, oh-my-zsh

I got an image from Facebook which is beautiful i want to make my Arch Linux machine just like this image,
[image]
 I have installed Arch Linux with Deepin Desktop Environment also installed neofetch, i am stuck on zsh shell theme which you can see in image, i tried to search in oh-my-zsh repositories`https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Themes` but can't find also i am unable to install Arc-Flatabulous theme & Flat-Remix icons

Comment: have you installed `zsh-shell` successfully in your arch linux, if yes, are you struggling to install the theme shown in above image? please let me know the answer for my both the question...

Comment: Yes, i have installed zsh successfully in my arch linux & i am struggling to find theme that one.

Comment: It might not even be a "theme" (in the sense of a ready made package); it could also be a custom made prompt. And even, if it is a ready mad theme it might be from some other configuration framework like `prezto`. Unless the author of the screenshot shared their configuration, it might be hard to find. Of course, you could try to recreate it from the screenshot…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below instruction:

first list all the install shell in your current system:
`chsh -l`

then change your shell like this: (in your case zsh:
`chsh -s /bin/zsh`

and now restart or logout and login.

then install oh-my-zsh theme from here :

`https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh`

installation command looks like:

`sh -c "$(wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh -O -)"`

after this open file `~/zshrc`: `nano ~/.zshrc`

and change the `ZSH_THEME` to: `ZSH_THEME="fino"` (you can set to any theme you like)

now open a new terminal.. and check its work or not.

let me know this works or not. if its work..

add a screenshot in your question and mark my post as answer.

Answer (score 1):

The theme in your screenshot is jovial.
It can be found here: https://github.com/zthxxx/jovial